# Why the button does nothing? javafx

Tags: javafx

so i'm creating this application using javafx which has one login screen, but I've had no sucess at all in this, I have been working on this little part of the project for some days and it simply didn't work in any way I try to do it, I watched some tutorials and most of them were making like the codes below, yet it didn't work for me, if anyone can help me with that explaining why my label text doesn't change(that's how I'm testing if the login was sucessful) it would be nice, here are the codes:

```
package application;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/telaLogin.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("morrer");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 380, 450));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private TextField username;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField pfSenha;

    @FXML
    private Label labelTeste;

    public void login(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        if(username.getText().equals("admin") && pfSenha.getText().equals("admin")) {
            labelTeste.setText("sucess");
        } else {
            labelTeste.setText("fail");
        }
    }
}
```

FXML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane fx:id="telaLogin" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="333.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.LoginController">
    <center>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="408.0" prefWidth="333.0" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER">
            <children>
                <TextField fx:id="username" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="184.0" promptText="Usuáro">
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                    </VBox.margin>
                </TextField>
            <PasswordField fx:id="pfSenha" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="184.0" promptText="  Senha">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="50.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </PasswordField>
            <Button fx:id="btnEntrar" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets right="25.0" top="50.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </center>
   <bottom>
      <Label fx:id="labelTeste" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="289.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button does nothing because FX does not know it should call `login` method in your `LoginController`.
Following this [FX GUI tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/javafx-fxml-form-gui-tutorial/) you have to specify called method in `onAction` attribute. So your button should be defined:

```xml
<Button onAction="#login" fx:id="btnEntrar" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
        minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button">
```

Comment: And decorate the `login` function in the controller with the `@FXML` annotation.

Comment: @FXML annotation is required only for not public fields

Comment: really, I never knew that.